# Is this an accurate explanation of a covariance matrix?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My intent is to provide a simpler description, instead of a mathematical proof, and a practical example of a covariance matrix, especially as they are used in ROS.

Did I hit the mark with:

[Covariance matrices with a practical example](http://manialabs.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/covariance-matrices-with-a-practical-example/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41764/is-this-an-accurate-explanation-of-a-covariance-matrix?/) by [billmania](https://answers.ros.org/users/1420/billmania/) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2012-08-17

Post score: 18

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2016-05-26**:
Thanks! Helped my understanding of it. (4 years later it's still helping people)

**Comment by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) on 2017-10-31**:
I found it helpful 5 years later :)

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-10**:
nice read, 6 years later

**Comment by [indraneel](https://answers.ros.org/users/35902/indraneel/) on 2019-06-06**:
Still a great read 7 years later!

**Comment by [xinwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/36542/xinwf/) on 2019-07-25**:
Nice, very comprehensive

**Comment by [denim](https://answers.ros.org/users/52190/denim/) on 2020-03-02**:
Helpful, 8 years later!

**Comment by [berkayaskar](https://answers.ros.org/users/126314/berkayaskar/) on 2022-12-07**:
Helpful 10 years later!

**Comment by [billmania](https://answers.ros.org/users/1420/billmania/) on 2022-12-12**:
On occasion, one manages to understand something. Sometimes, others find it useful. I'm pleased to see this explanation has survived for ten years. I didn't expect that to happen way back in 2012 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Great read, very informative. Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) with karma: 399 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8